# How to plot the accuracy and and loss from this DNN model and How to improve model accuracy?

Tags: python, matplotlib, deep-learning, visualization

```
!pip install tflearn
!pip install textblob

import nltk
nltk.download('punkt')
from nltk.stem.lancaster import LancasterStemmer
stemmer = LancasterStemmer()
from textblob import TextBlob
import numpy
import tflearn
import tensorflow
import random
import json
import pickle

with open("intents.json") as file:
    data = json.load(file)

try:
    with open("data.pickle", "rb") as f:
        words, labels, training, output = pickle.load(f)
except:
    words = []
    labels = []
    docs_x = []
    docs_y = []

    for intent in data["intents"]:
        for pattern in intent["patterns"]:
            wrds = nltk.word_tokenize(pattern)
            words.extend(wrds)
            docs_x.append(wrds)
            docs_y.append(intent["tag"])

        if intent["tag"] not in labels:
            labels.append(intent["tag"])

    words = [stemmer.stem(w.lower()) for w in words if w != "?"]
    words = sorted(list(set(words)))

    labels = sorted(labels)

    training = []
    output = []

    out_empty = [0 for _ in range(len(labels))]

    for x, doc in enumerate(docs_x):
        bag = []

        wrds = [stemmer.stem(w.lower()) for w in doc]

        for w in words:
            if w in wrds:
                bag.append(1)
            else:
                bag.append(0)

        output_row = out_empty[:]
        output_row[labels.index(docs_y[x])] = 1

        training.append(bag)
        output.append(output_row)


    training = numpy.array(training)
    output = numpy.array(output)

    with open("data.pickle", "wb") as f:
        pickle.dump((words, labels, training, output), f)

from tensorflow.python.framework import ops
ops.reset_default_graph()

net = tflearn.input_data(shape=[None, len(training[0])])
net = tflearn.fully_connected(net, 8)
net = tflearn.fully_connected(net, 8)
net = tflearn.fully_connected(net, len(output[0]), activation="softmax")
net = tflearn.regression(net)

model = tflearn.DNN(net)

try:
    model.load("model.tflearn")
except:
    train = model.fit(training, output, n_epoch=2000, batch_size=8, show_metric=True)
    model.save("model.tflearn")

def bag_of_words(s, words):
    bag = [0 for _ in range(len(words))]

    s_words = nltk.word_tokenize(s)
    s_words = [stemmer.stem(word.lower()) for word in s_words]

    for se in s_words:
        for i, w in enumerate(words):
            if w == se:
                bag[i] = 1
            
    return numpy.array(bag)
    
def chat():
    print("Welcome to Bot (type quit to stop)!")
    while True:
        inp = input("You: ")
        if inp.lower() == "quit":
            break
            
        #getting sentiment analysis value
        edu=TextBlob(inp)
        sa=edu.sentiment.polarity
        print("Sentiment Value is : ",sa)    

        results = model.predict([bag_of_words(inp, words)])[0]
        results_index = numpy.argmax(results)
        tag = labels[results_index]

        if results[results_index] > 0.7:
            for tg in data["intents"]:
              if tg['tag'] == tag:
                  responses = tg['bot_response']

            print(random.choice(responses))

        else:
            print("I didn't get that, try again.")

chat()
```

The code below is for my DNN model and I want to plot the accuracy and loss for it, any help would be much appreciated. I like the output to be plotted using matplotlib so need any advice as I'm not sure how to approach this. Two plots with training and validation accuracy and another plot with training and validation loss. And also how to apply to improve the accuracy of this model?